# Bootstrap Tooltip position disorder when in large size

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am using bootstrap tooltip with fullcalendar.js (but the problem is not in the fullcalendar lib, I just included it whatever.)

Problem is here on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/byu14uyu/). You will see the tooltip that keeps on flashing.

This is very easy to fix if I remove the `overflow-y:scroll` in the .container to be look like this

```
.container{
  height:300px;
  width:220px;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Unfortunately, I need that `overflow-y:scroll`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add:

> boundary: 'viewport'

in the options for the tooltip function call:

```
$( document ).ready($('.hastooltip').tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        boundary: 'viewport',
        trigger: 'hover',
        template: '<div class="tooltip ' + tooptipClass + '" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'}));
```

Check the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/byu14uyu/7/).